# The data types varchar(max) and date are incompatible in the add operator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created one of the search SP here, Just preparing parameters based on user input on screen.

Now I need to cast the table column as well as input parameter with `DATE` type and then need to query.

Below is the part of the procedure which I need to achieve.

Problem is, I'm getting the following error now:

> The data types varchar(max) and date are incompatible in the add operator.

```
DECLARE @WhereClause VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DateField DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @DateFieldTo DATETIME =  GETDATE() +1

SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' AND CAST(tbl.DateField AS DATE) BETWEEN ''' + CAST(@DateField AS DATE) + ''' + AND ''' +  CAST(@DateFieldTo AS DATE)+ ''        

PRINT @WhereClause
```

I tried the below approach:

```
DECLARE @WhereClause VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DateField DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @DateFieldTo DATETIME =  GETDATE() +1
DECLARE @YourSQLVariable VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' AND CAST(tbl.DateField AS DATE) BETWEEN  CAST(@DateField AS DATE) + AND  CAST(@DateFieldTo AS DATE)'

SET @YourSQLVariable = 'SELECT 1 WHERE' + @WhereClause

EXEC sp_executeSQL @YourSQLVariable,N'@DateField   DATETIME,@DateFieldTo DATETIME ',@DateField,@DateFieldTo
```

And got:

> Error: Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'.

Comment: You'll have to cast the part `CAST(@DateField AS DATE)` to `varchar` first.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you are trying to concatenate a `DATE` type `CAST(tbl.DateField AS DATE)` with a string `@WhereClause`, which is not supported, in this line:

```
  SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' AND CAST(tbl.DateField AS DATE) BETWEEN ''' + CAST(@DateField AS DATE) + ''' + AND ''' +  CAST(@DateFieldTo AS DATE)+ ''
```

You can achieve this using something like this:

```
  SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' AND CAST(tbl.DateField AS DATE) BETWEEN  CAST(@DateField AS DATE) + AND  CAST(@DateFieldTo AS DATE)'
```

and when running `sp_executeSQL`, use this:

```
@YourSQLVariable = @SelectClause + @WhereClause
EXEC sp_executeSQL @YourSQLVariable,N'@DateField DATETIME,@DateFieldTo DATETIME ',@DateField,@DateFieldTo
```

Comment: I tried that on sample script as shown in above edited question but, gave another error. Please guide.

Comment: it's because as the error states `sp_executeSQL` expects a parameter of type `ntext/nchar/nvarchar`. Change your variable `@YourSQLVariable` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for date casting or date comparison only w.r.t date,

```
DECLARE @SqlQuery VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @UserId VARCHAR(MAX) = 'TestUser'
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = DATEADD(WEEK, -6, GETDATE())
SET @SqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM User Z WHERE Z.Id = ''' + @UserId + ''' AND CAST(Z.CreatedDate AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(24), @StartDate, 101) + ''' AS DATE) AND CAST(''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(24), @ENDDATE, 101)  +''' AS DATE)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate date objects with strings:

```
DECLARE @WhereClause VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @DateField DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @DateFieldTo DATETIME =  GETDATE() +1

SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),tbl.DateField,120) BETWEEN ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@DateField,120) + ''' + AND ''' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@DateFieldTo,120)+ ''''        

PRINT @WhereClause
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not allow strings to be concatenated with other data types.

```
DECLARE @WhereClause VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @DateField DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @DateFieldTo DATETIME =  GETDATE() +1

SET @WhereClause = @WhereClause + ' AND CAST(tbl.DateField AS DATE) BETWEEN '''  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @DateField, 120) + ''' AND ''' +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(25), @DateFieldTo, 120) + ''''

PRINT @WhereClause
```

Also, the @WhereClause was not defined, so the concatenation was not working with the initial null string.